# Problems recreating LINQ query from SQL script

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm struggling in 'translating' a SQL query to a LINQ query. My SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT S.SummonerName, LE.LeaguePoints, LS.DateTime, SUM(LE.LeaguePoints)
FROM LadderEntries LE
JOIN Sumonners S on LE.SummonerId = S.Id
JOIN LadderSnapshots LS on LE.LadderSnapshotId = LS.Id
WHERE LS.Region = 'euw1'
AND DateTime = '2019-06-14 00:00:00'
OR DateTime = '2019-06-13 00:00:00'
and LS.Region = 'euw1'
GROUP BY S.SummonerName
```

This query gives me the desired result. However, so far I got the following LINQ query:

```
from LE in _database.LadderEntries
join S in _database.Sumonners on LE.SummonerId equals S.Id
join LS in _database.LadderSnapshots on LE.LadderSnapshot.Id equals LS.Id
where LS.Region == param.Region && (LS.DateTime == param.Date || LS.DateTime == param.Date.AddDays(-1))
group new {LE, S, LS} by S.SummonerName
into C
select new GetLadderEntryDifferencesEntry
{
    LpDifference = C.Select(a => a.LE.LeaguePoints).Sum(),
    SummonerName = C.Select(a => a.S.SummonerName).FirstOrDefault()
};
```

But this gives me the error `InvalidOperationException: Error generated for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryClientEvaluationWarning: The LINQ expression 'GroupBy([S].SummonerName, new <>f__AnonymousType5'3(LE = [LE], S = [S], LS = [LS]))' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.'.` on execution.

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Note: I'm using sqllite and ef core if that makes a difference.

Comment: EF core is really tricky you get surprised with what you can't do, buy first change the FirstOrDefault to C.Key and change and your sql does a sum and the line dose some sort of aggregate so change it to.C.Sum(a=>a.LeaguePoints) if that was the intent.

Comment: These queries are functionally different (return different results) though - SQL does sum while LINQ does difference?

Comment: @IvanStoev I changed it. I was messing around with the code, forgot to change it back.

Comment: @FilipCordas I changed the select object to `{
                    LpDifference = C.Sum(a => a.LE.LeaguePoints),
                    SummonerName = C.Key
                }`, however this gives me the same error

Comment: I am surprised by this but EF Core is really really bad group by was an issue for a [loooooong time](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/2341) maybe the `new {LE, S, LS}` try changing it to `new {S.SummonerName, LE.LeaguePoints}` and that do a sum on  `C.Sum(a => a.LeaguePoints)` and same Key select also maybe try changing it from new GetLadderEntryDifferencesEntry{… to new {....

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue will be with:

`&& (LS.DateTime == param.Date || LS.DateTime == param.Date.AddDays(-1))`

try this:

```
var firstDate = param.Date;
var secondDate = param.Date.AddDays(-1);
```

then

`&& (LS.DateTime == firstDate || LS.DateTime == secondDate)`

possibly it may be taking exception to:
`SummonerName = C.Select(a => a.S.SummonerName).FirstOrDefault()`
or how the grouping is arranged.

Are these entities set up with references and can the expression be simplified?

```
var ladderEntryDifferences = _database.LadderSnapshots
    .Where(x =>x.Region = param.Region 
        && (x => x.DateTime == firstDate || x.DateTime == secondDate)
    .GroupBy(x => x.LadderEntry.Summoner.SummonerName)
    .Select( g => new GetLadderEntryDifferencesEntry
    {
        LpDifference = g.Sum(x => x.LeagueEntry.LeaguePoints),
        SummonerName = g.Key // This will be the SummonerName
    }).ToList();
```

The above is a guess about the structure, and pulling the group by from memory, but it might give you some ideas to try. If your context does not expose LadderSnapshots at a top level, you should be able to compose it from the LadderEntry level as well...

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is what i got, first

```
LS.Region = 'euw1'
AND DateTime = '2019-06-14 00:00:00'
OR DateTime = '2019-06-13 00:00:00'
and LS.Region = 'euw1'
```

is not the same as the below linq, where the parameters is missing in the sql.

```
&& (LS.DateTime == param.Date || LS.DateTime == param.Date.AddDays(-1))
```

Now about the group by you could try to do it like this instead

```
from LE in _database.LadderEntries
join S in _database.Sumonners on LE.SummonerId equals S.Id
join LS in _database.LadderSnapshots on LE.LadderSnapshot.Id equals LS.Id
where LS.Region == param.Region && (LS.DateTime == param.Date || LS.DateTime == param.Date.AddDays(-1))
group LE by new {LE.SummonerName, S.SummonerName, LS.SummonerName} 
into C
select new GetLadderEntryDifferencesEntry
{
    LpDifference = C.Select(a => a.LE.LeaguePoints).Sum(),
    SummonerName = C.Select(a => a.S.SummonerName).FirstOrDefault()
};
```